# TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj in jquery 1.9.1 version

Tags: jquery

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: url+"module/listing/"+projectId,
    data: "ajax=true",
    success: function(response) {
        $.each(response, function(key, val) {
        alert(val.id);
        });
    }
});
```

This is my code. Ajax success I am getting JSON response. Response is in array format. And I want to alert the response. But getting error `"TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj"`  for JQuery 1.9.1 version.

Comment: What browser are you testing this on?

Answer (score 10):

```
success: function(response) {
        response=JSON.parse(response);
        $.each(response, function(key, val) {
        alert(val.id);
        });
    }
```

Comment: not working I added  responce=JSON.parse(responce);  But not getting prper answer.

Comment: please, mention the output from php script. you can see in console within firebug.

Comment: This should be marked as correct. It solved the issue for me as well.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error after I encoded twice a JSON array. Maybe it will help anybody.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The error is being triggered from the jQuery function 'isArraylike( obj )' from the following line:

```
return type === "array" || type !== "function" &&
    ( length === 0 ||
    typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && ( length - 1 ) in obj );
```

The Javascript 'in' operator needs an object as operand, so chances are if you do jQuery.type(response) it'll show something other than an object (eg. string or null)

So Amit's answer should work - if not, check the type of the response data and work from there.

Answer (score 2):

Use `dataType: "json"` to have jQuery parse the response as JSON. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Same error, in my case instead of defining local as an array, I was defining it as a string. `JSON.parse` it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, worked for me

```
$.each(eval(response), function(key, val)
```

For some reason (which I don't know), response is considered a string and not an object so you have to 'convert it' using `eval()`.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error while sending an array of column names to jQuery DataTables.  The array needs to be an array of objects, not just an array of names. [link to columns](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns)

BAD
columns: ["Column1", "Column2"]

GOOD
columns:[{title: "Column1"}, {title: "Column2"}]